# Laravel 5 variable not being recognised

Tags: php, laravel, variables, laravel-5, routes

Bit of an odd problem which is probably because I am finding my feet with Laravel.

I have an edit page which is accessed by:

```
Route::get('editRow/{id}', function($id){
    $section = App\Section::where('id', $id)->with('panels')->first();
    return view('front.editrow',['thesection'=>$section]);
});
```

This form then is completed and goes to a controller with a longish method to update the table and ends with:

```
return view('front.editrow',['message'=>'update successful','id'=>$request->id]);
```

The DB is updated OK. Initially I was getting an error so I copied the route and changed it from a get to a post:

```
Route::post('editRow/{id}', function($id){
    $section = App\Section::where('id', $id)->with('panels')->first();
    return view('front.editrow',['thesection'=>$section]);
});
```

Now although this is exactly the same parameters etc I always get;

```
Undefined variable: thesection
```

I am baffled and would greatly appreciate this mystery being solved!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that **thesection** variable is always passed to the view.

When you do:

```
return view('front.editrow',['message'=>'update successful', 'id'=>$request->id]);
```

this variable is not provided. You need to either provide it in the view or check for its existence in the blade template with:

```
@if(isset($thesection)
  // whatever you want to do with the section
@endif
```